# Blob download not triggered on Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently creating something that generates a `PDF` / `CSV` file on local and makes it available to download. My current code is working everywhere except on Windows Phone (especially Lumia) which seems to not handle BLOB Url.

How could I fix this issue and force the download?

```
vm.showPdf = function (documentKey) {
var requestPayloadForShowPdf = {
    "DocumentList": documentKey,
    "AccountNumber": selectedAccountNumber
};
documentsService.getPdf(requestPayloadForShowPdf).then(function (obj) {
    if (!obj.HasErrors) {
        vm.isdispalyApiErrorMessage = false;
        var byteCharacters = atob(obj.PdfDocument);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new window.Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });

        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "Statements(" + utilService.getLastFourDigits(selectedAccountNumber) + ").pdf");
        } else {
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(url);
        }
    } else {
        vm.isdispalyApiErrorMessage = true;
        vm.dispalyApiErrorMessage = utilService.getLiteralFromTranslate('stndrdAPIErrorMsg');//documentsResponse.Errors[0].Description;
    }
});
```

};

Comment: Did you try to set the header Content-Type: application/octet-stream ?

Comment: Please add your source code.

Comment: Please read [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @gp_sflover. I added my code snippet as well.